# SQL CLR Function Using Quartz.net

Tags: quartz.net, sqlclr

Am trying to create a CLR function and inside am using below quartz.net code snippet

```
 public static class SqlCron
{
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static DateTimeOffset? GetNearestDate(SqlString expression, SqlDateTime baseDateTime)
    {
        if (expression.IsNull || baseDateTime.IsNull)
            return (DateTime?)null;

        try
        {
            var schedule = new CronExpression(expression.Value);
            var res = schedule.GetTimeAfter(baseDateTime.Value);
            return res;
            //return new DateTimeOffset();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (DateTime?)null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to register this assembly to SQL server throwing exception.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyCron
FROM 'D:\Projects\MyCron\bin\Debug\MyCron.dll' 
--WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE--UNSAFE --EXTERNAL_ACCESS --PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION CronNearestDate(
    @Expression NVARCHAR(100), 
    @BaseDateTime DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [MyCron].[MyCron.SqlCron].[GetNearestDate]
GO


sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

--Every month last day
--0 59 23 L * ? *
select dbo.CronNearestDate('0 59 23 L * ? *', GETDATE())
GO
```

The above will register the assembly and create the SQL clr function. But it is failed in the assembly registration itself

The error would be

Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.diagnostics.tracing, version=4.2.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 6586, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual exception

Comment: Here you go Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.diagnostics.tracing, version=4.2.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 6586, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used

Comment: The problem seems to be `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`. What happens if you create your assembly as `UNSAFE`? Remember not all assemblies can be used in SQLCLR, regardless of permission set.

Comment: Can we take it this way, Quartz.net can't be used for SQL CLR?